# How to record screen on graphicdesign.stackexchange?

Tags: gif, video

I've seen some answers on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com where people have made small recordings of how they navigate menus to show someone where a particular item is located. These are usually animated gifs and not videos.

What software is being used to create these?

What is this type of video called? It isn't an animated gif because animations aren't being used. Someone recorded a small section of their screen and uploaded the recording as a gif.

Here is an example:
[Keep pixels crisp when rotating object?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/122184/keep-pixels-crisp-when-rotating-object)

Comment: One answer: https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/790/how-to-embed-screen-capture-videos-as-animated-gifs-in-answers There are other methods though.

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/83224/23061

Comment: Unfortunately, not what I'm asking about. All of those require heavy lifting and multiple programs or exports out of a full blown screen recorder for video.

Comment: Actually, as I read things, my link is **exactly** what you asked about. It generally *can't* all be done with 1 simple step. Perhaps you can edit the question to explain more, if none of these links are answering things for you? If you just want "something to do it for me" then I'm afraid you may be out of luck.

Comment: All different software can do it, but I use: Sharex. It's free and Open Source. It has a GIF screen recording function in 1 single step.  Yes, these are called animated GIFs.